# How to copy data from two different table and insert fetched records into another table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to insert data in my table which have 3 feild

```
 (1) sendReqID type int(PK)
 (2) RequestID type int (FK from table Request)
 (3) DonorID type int (FK table Donor)
```

I know how to copy data from one table and insert into another table but I want to know how to insert data in table, when we have to extract values from two different tables. Following is my code which I am trying and unable to insert data into my table.

```
public void Req_SendID()
{
    SqlConnection MySQL = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ToString());
    string copy = "insert into Send_Request(RequestID,DonorID) Select RequestID,DonorID from RequestID and DonorID from Donor where R_City='" + Session["BGroup"] + "' and" + "D_City='" + Session["city"] + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(copy, MySQL);
    MySQL.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MySQL.Close();
}
```

Please Help thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any connection between request and donor table?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What is your column types? And put a white space before `"D_City='"` part. Of course you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @SonerGönül I want to check total requests which has been sent to a particular donor and show him on his account.

Comment: @Sachu no there is no direct connection between donor and request table

Answer (score 1):

You need to `join` on the two tables...

```
insert into Send_Request(RequestID,DonorID) 
    Select r.RequestID, d.DonorID 
    from RequestID r inner join Donor d ON r.R_City = d.D_City
    where R_City='" + Session["BGroup"] + "' and " + "D_City='" + Session["city"] + "'"
```

I'm assuming the relationship is as above.  However, consider **[SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)** attacks and look to *parametrize* your query.

**EDIT**: Using Parameterized Query

```
var requestCity = Session["BGroup"].ToString();
var donorCity = Session["city"].ToString();

"insert into Send_Request(RequestID,DonorID) 
        Select r.RequestID, d.DonorID 
        from RequestID r inner join Donor d ON r.R_City = d.D_City
        where R_City=@RequestCity and D_City=@DonorCity"
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(copy, MySQL);
com.Parameters.Add("@RequestCity", requestCity);
com.Parameters.Add("@DonorCity", donorCity);
....
```

However, I just saw your comment that there is no relationship between the tables, so the actual query above would be incorrect.

Comment: Donor tale and Request table have no direct relation that's why i had created this table just to keep record.

Comment: @IbtisamTanveer, Did that not work? I see you removed accepted answer.

Comment: it didn't work, as there is no common column in between Donor and Request table so joins could not work for my case.